# Get all matching Strings in a Table

Tags: lua

I had a search string like "function *()". * is a wildcard. I want a table with a list of all matching strings.

e.g.
If I search this string with the searchstring "function *()"

```
function one()
  print("Hello")
end

local function two()
  print("World")
end
```

It should return the table {"function one()","function two()"}. How can I do this in LUA?

Comment: `retrurn {one,two}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local function search(text, searchstring)
   local result = {}
   local pattern = searchstring:gsub("*", "\0"):gsub("%p", "%%%0"):gsub("%z", ".-")
   for w in text:gmatch(pattern) do
      table.insert(result, w)
   end
   return result
end
```

Usage:

```
local text = [[
function one()
  print("Hello")
end

local function two()
  print("World")
end
]]

local searchstring = "function *()"

local result = search(text, searchstring)   --> {"function one()", "function two()"}
```